# xen-hypervisor - right way of snapshot and revert

Tags: rollback, snapshot, revert, xen, lvm

I have an CentOS 7 with **xen-hypervisor** 4.6.6.
I manage the VMs from **cli** with xen-tools (xl, etc).
The VM disks are managed with **LVM**.

I would like to create **snapshot of VM** and **revert** if needed (eg.: in case of failed system update).
Please tell me the **right way** to do it and these steps.

Thanks for the help!
(and sorry for my english)

Comment: Hi XCross, I have added where i am on the same issue than you right now. Waiting for an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually facing the same issue by trying Xen-hypervisor (not xen-server neither xen-api) and i will add some more information here.

From now this is what i found: https://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-snapshots-in-Xen-with-Linux-commands

The main difference from this topic is that I use xl and not xm.

Now, I have my snapshot.img and my snapshot.sav (cf topic).
I dont know what to do with those since xl restore seems to just restore the domain and when i use dd back to put the disk image in the LVM partition, i dont succeed to launch again the VM.

Any advice on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Coming back on this topic, i ended up using XenOrchestra to handle snapshot and export.

Also, one big mistake i had in my mind was confusing snapshot and export (image).
A snapshot is a state in time of your vm whereas an export is the entire vm. I was trying to use a snapshot to recreate a vm after removal which does not make sense.

Also, i think that you can do it easily with XenCenter.